# Example of package to showcase inheritance with physics or mathematical model?

Tags: inheritance, physics, modelica

I have an assignment to make a package in Modelica to showcase inheritance and duplication. The package has to be fully functional and has to be simulated with examples. This means that I need some sort of physics or mathematical model which can be made with one base class, and several inherited/duplicated classes.

The teacher made an example using a PID controller, where the P controller was the base class, and PI and PID was inherited.

I'm looking for examples or suggestions for what I can make a package about. I find it hard to find physics or something to model which can be expanded easily for a new concept.

Also looking for something not too complex.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite some possibilities. First it would make sense to browse through the Modelica Standard Library to get an impression of what is possible. Besides that, these should be worth a look:

1. [Modelica by Example](https://mbe.modelica.university/components/components/elec_comps/) on electrical components
2. [Claytex's Dymola Basics](https://www.claytex.com/blog/dymola-basics-8-dymola-model-inheritance/) on mechanical components

There are many more available...